# Python:- Using Copy to take value of static variable within a class

Tags: python, copy, mutable

I am trying to complete an exercise and as part of this I am creating 7 Node objects.

```
import copy
class Node (object):
    nodedesignation = 0 # this is a static class variable.
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        Node.nodedesignation +=1
        self.designation = copy.deepcopy(Node.nodedesignation)
        #self.designation = Node.nodedesignation - original code. same result
        print (self.designation)
```

I am trying to have each node have an individual designation (self.designation) so that the first created node will have a nodedesignation = 1 and the 7th created node will have nodedesignation =7.

**PROBLEM**
This works fine upon initialisation of each Node however, when the static variable Node.nodedesignation is incremented by 1, each of the node designations also is increased. (self.nodedesignation = 7 for every node after initialisation of all nodes)

I had thought that copy.deepcopy would make self.designation independent from modifications to Node.nodedesignation however, I still get the same result. How can I make these variables independent of each other?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`nodedesignation` is a class attribute, so each instance has the same, but you create an attribute `designation` for each instance, so this attribute is individual.

Btw. copy is not necessary, because `int`s are immutable.

```
class Node (object):
    nodedesignation = 0 # this is a class attribute.
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.right = None
        self.left = None
        Node.nodedesignation += 1 # increment the class attribute
        self.designation = Node.nodedesignation # use it's value as instance attribute
        print(self.designation)
```

Creating different `Node`s, each has its own `designation`:

```
node1 = Node(1)
node2 = Node(2)
node3 = Node(3)
print(node1.designation)
# 1
print(node2.designation)
# 2
print(node3.designation)
# 3
```

Comment: Hi Daniel,
Thanks for the response. Your solution is how I had originally implemented my code but found that this had the same issue. I agree that I would expect this to correctly assign each node with a unique self.designation however once all seven nodes are created, the self.designation of each node is 7.

I think there is another factor at play. This suggests to me that self.designation is still referencing the value of Node.nodedesignation which is not desirable.

Comment: @Didgeridude: see my edit. Everything works as expected.